# How to specifiy enumeration literal as default value in UML Attribute?

Tags: attributes, uml, default-value, metamodel

I currently doing some model transformations using EMF-UML-Implementation.
In my model transformation I create an uml class with some attributes. The attributes are type of enumerations I also created.
Some of the attribute should get a default value. The default value should be enumeration literals.

The question now is, how do I get the enumeration literals to the `defaultValue`-property of the `Property`.

I already have found that I have to use `ValueSpecification`. But the UML superstructure says not much about that (page 139 f.). Which properties do I have to use for setting the defaultValue to enumeration literals?

I think the main problem I have is, that the use of `ValueSpecification` is unclear to me. Currently I only use `default` to set the default values, which is type of String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultValue`-property takes a `ValueSpecification` argument. So in your case, you need an `InstanceValue` for this purpose (which derives from `ValueSpecification`). The `InstanceValue` itself has an `instance`-property, which takes an `InstanceSpecification` as argument. As `EnumerationLiteral` derives from `InstanceSpecification`, you can now simply assign one of your `EnumerationLiterals` to it.