# UML: Real and UnlimitedNatural literals

Tags: uml

I am not sure that my notation of Real and UnlimitedNatural literals are correct so I did this example. Please, say if this notation is right or wrong.

```
-----------------------------
|       MyClass             |
-----------------------------
| var1:Real=0.87            |
| var2:Real=1.6E-2          |
| var3:UnlimitedNumber=5..* |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Are you trying to express multiplicities or default values?

Comment: @Peter I am trying to express default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default value is described by a `ValueSpecification` (as noted in Chapter 9.5. of UML specs, or here [How to specifiy enumeration literal as default value in UML Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989969/how-to-specifiy-enumeration-literal-as-default-value-in-uml-attribute)).

In your case, you are interested in Reals, and UnlimitedNaturals.

> 8.4.2 Notation
>
> - A LiteralUnlimitedNatural is shown either as a sequence of digits or as an asterisk (*), where an asterisk
>     denotes unlimited. Note that “unlimited” denotes the lack of a limit on the value of some element (such as a
>     multiplicity upper bound), not a value of “infinity.”
> - A LiteralReal is shown in decimal notation or scientific notation. Decimal notation consists of an optional sign
>     character (+/-) followed by zero or more digits followed optionally by a dot (.) followed by one or more digits.
>     Scientific notation consists of decimal notation followed by either the letter “e” or “E” and an exponent
>     consisting of an optional sign character followed by one or more digits. The scientific notation expresses a real
>     number equal to that given by the decimal notation before the exponent, times 10 raised to the power of the
>     exponent.

So `var1` and `var2` are correct, however `var3` is not.

`5..*` is a multiplicity expressing "*at least 5 values*", having it as a default value isn't really meaningful.

As for `LiteralUnlimitedNatural`, this is meaningful primarily for multiplicities, where you can use it to express lack of upper bound.
For default value it is no different to `LiteralInteger` with constraint `>=0` --- any non-negative number.

`Integer` is any whole number: -2, 0, 27, ...

`Natural` is any non-negative (>=0) number: 0, 120, ...

`UnlmitedNatural` is a `Natural` number or an asterisk `*`, which means lack of limit;
however `*` is not a value of itself (it doesn't mean infinity as noted above), but rather lack of value in a specific (multiplicity range) context.

Comment: Could you provide examples for UnlimitedNumber literals?

Comment: for default values it is just a non-negative number; what exactly are you trying to express with the `5..*` default value?

Comment: I wrote 5..* trying to understand what is the UnlimitedNumber. What is the difference between UnlimitedNumber and Integer?

Comment: Peter already mentioned this in his answer, but maybe this makes it easier to understand: `UnlimitedNatural = Integer - (all negative numbers) + *`